# Youtube Video in netbeans windows application Java

Tags: java, video, netbeans, youtube

hi im making a windows application in java and was wondering if it is possible to have a youtube viewer on it. so that when the window loads a specific video is there from youtube ready to be watched? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Youtube in java check out the API for details

[Youtube API for Java](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)